# How to run VsCode's Code Runner in an external terminal?

Tags: command-line, c++, visual-studio-code, xterm

I would like to launch the c++ app using Code Runner of Visual Studio Code in an External Terminal.

---

There was a

[Similar Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367348/in-visual-studio-code-launch-a-console-application-in-an-external-window) 
[Similar Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221544/how-to-make-code-runner-run-in-external-terminal-command-prompt)

on the internet but it focused on Vscode in windows or required some XTERM(that didn't work either) and since I am new, I have no idea what that is.